# Base URL for GitLab self-managed API

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I am doing a project in which I need to get responses from Gitlab self-managed.

For Gitlab SaaS it's very easy to find and use the baseurl, however I am facing some difficulties understanding what is my base url in the self-managed option.

Couldn't find an answer in Gitlab API docs - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/

I tried querying both the address of the self-managed server and the SaaS base url both unsuccessfully.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [how to use the API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#how-to-use-the-api), the API is located at the `api/v4` path.

For example, to use the projects API on gitlab.com, you can use: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects